# How to publish MVC app with proxy if Azure does not use same web.config as my local environment

Tags: azure

In my MVC web app, one controller function (Validate) calls a service. See below code and note that MessageHandlerClient is a service proxy generated in Visual Studio. The service proxy call client.ValidateMessage(formdataasbson["HLmessage"].ToString())  works fine in my local dev environment. When I publish the project to Azure, calls to Validate controller function no longer work. Suspecting a problem with the proxy, I changed Validate() to give back hard-coded results, re-publish to Azure, and all works fine - confirming a problem with the web service proxy behavior in Azure.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Validate(String serializedformdata)
    {
        try
        {
            BsonDocument formdataasbson = this.serializer.JSONFormtoBSON(serializedformdata);    
            MessageHandlerClient client = new MessageHandlerClient();
            this.jsonresponse.ReturnValue = "true";

            StandaloneValidator.My_ServiceReference.Error[] results = client.ValidateMessage(formdataasbson["HLmessage"].ToString());       

            this.jsonresponse.ReturnMessage = results.ToJson();

            return Json(this.jsonresponse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.jsonresponse.ReturnValue = "false";
            this.jsonresponse.ReturnMessage = ex.Message;
            return Json(this.jsonresponse);

        }

    }
```

What's more, I see details of the web service proxy in my local web.config file as below (IP intentionally obscured):

I have read various posts about web.config in Azure and the fact that it is not writable, so I'm suspecting my local ..... proxy info is never published in Azure. If indeed web.config does not publish from local to Azure, then I understand why my proxy doesn't work. The question is.....what should I do to fix??!

EDIT: I see various posts discussing migration of some settings from web.config to csfg files for Azure - perhaps a viable solution? Given that I am not coding manual read of these settings (I simply created service proxy from URL to service) I worry about auto-generated code or any "under-the-hood" behavior of the service not knowing how to read migrated settings from csfg.

Comment: Are you publishing to Windows Azure Websites or Windows Azure Cloud Services?

Comment: Have you RDP'd into your instance to confirm the web.config settings?

Comment: I am publishing to Azure Websites. Note the web service of interest/concern here is hosted elsewhere....it is not an Azure service. The controller MVC web app acts as a client to call the web service.

Comment: I had naively expected publishing my MVC site to Azure would properly carry local web.config up to the server. Now as I read more, web.config isn't editable in Azure websites. Let's say I RDP and confirm what we expect - that web.config in Azure doesn't contain service endpoints. Then what can I do to resolve my issue? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or out of the norm by trying to publish a MVC app with a controller that calls a service? Said another way....what's the standard way to publish a web app that itself calls a non-Azure web service?

Comment: Possible same problem reported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769108/how-to-put-system-servicemodel-into-serviceconfiguration-cscfg-windows-azure

Comment: Yet more on this topic: http://blogs.staykov.net/2009/08/azure-worker-role-config-settings.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have written above, it seems you are confused with Web Role and Web Sites. First you would need to understand the difference between these two so you can make better decision on what to choose for your application. Here are some useful links:

- [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role/10942227#10942227) on difference between Azure Web Sites and Web Role
- [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj218759.aspx) on when and why to choose Azure Web Sites and Web Role and Azure VM

Windows Azure Web site, you do not have full control over IIS web server and because of that some of the settings web site specific settings are configurable and others are not. In Windows Azure websites, most of machine and system specific settings added into web.config are overwritten so these settings does not work. Also you can not RDP to your Azure Websites instance as well.

If you have to use ASP.NET MVC application which MUST need proxy configuration, you must deploy it to [Windows Azure Cloud Service](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Yes, I acknowledge my initial confusion on site vs. role. However, now I have also tried publishing the same project as a role instead of site....with identical results. Apparently creating a service proxy in a controller requires some config info. In standalone environment creating proxy automatically deposits relevant info to web.config and possibly other places, but auto-generation of service endpoint info does not publish to Azure properly. My root problem appears to be publishing a web service proxy to Azure. See other post as well. Thx!