# WaIISHost.exe.config vs. app.config for worker role config

Tags: azure

Posts seem to conflict in their description of how best to get web.config settings into an Azure worker role. Some posts say you need to create WaIISHost.exe.config, set output to always then copy relevant web.config info to that file. Other posts describe creation of app.config instead of WaIISHost.exe. Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this depends a bit on the version of the SDK you are using.  First and foremost, the WaIISHost.exe.config is only applicable to Web Roles (not worker roles).  Worker Roles use and continue to use app.config for their configuration settings.  I am going to assume here that you are trying to configure a Web Role's RoleEntryPoint in config settings.

Now, for Web Roles:  If you are using the latest SDK (1.8 at time of writing), you will find that creating a WaIISHost.exe.config file (and copy local, etc.) no longer works.  Something has changed in the latest SDK and it will no longer pull those values.  For earlier versions of the SDK, this is still how you do it.  For the latest version (and likely next versions) 1.8, you can create an app.config.  When you do that, it will actually create a file in your bin directory like "WebRoleProjectName.dll.config".  You DO NOT have to create this file manually yourself and "Copy Local".  Simply create the app.config like you normally would and you will find that your RoleEntryPoint in the Web Role can be configured just fine like that.

Comment: The problem with app.config in a web role is that right now it doesn't get deployed by the UI's Publish... command

Comment: Yeah, app.config won't work for a web worker role, if deployed through Visual Studio UI, but if you name your config file: ProjectName.dll.config and set it to copy always then it works. I just had the same issue.

Comment: During build, app.config is renamed to <Web Project Name>.dll.config and moved to the bin folder directly.  Anything that is in the bin folder is packaged and deployed for web roles.  Are you sure you have the app.config in the root directory and you checked the bin directory after build?  Works fine for me.

Comment: Doing build a <webprojectname>.dll.config is also created from the web.config (Azure SDK 2.2)

Comment: @pksorensen are you sure ? Doesn't work for me, I have to add a PROJECTNAME.dll.config with CopyAlways.

Comment: I am not sure any more because lately I have had to add <assemblyname>.dll.config also. Havent been able to figure out what triggers the web.config to <assembly>.dll.config transformation and just gave up on it in contrast to just adding the file my self.

Comment: But doesn't the `web.config` copy to the output directory as `<ProjectName>.dll.config`?

Answer (score 2):

In your previous [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061838/how-to-publish-mvc-app-with-proxy-if-azure-does-not-use-same-web-config-as-my-lo/14072783#14072783), I suggested that you would need to spend some time to understand both Windows Azure websites and Windows Azure Cloud services as you are mixing together.

Like above you are mixing web and worker role together. WaIISHost.exe is the Windows Azure Web Role Host process which is responsible for loading and running your Web Role DLL. This process has nothing to do with Worker role because it is not even existing in a Windows Azure Worker Role. This process will be only available to Web Roles. And because of that your question above "WaIISHost.exe.config vs. app.config for worker role config" is irrelevant.

App.config configuration is used with both Web Role and Worker Role, however web.config is only used with your web application. So if you want to configure Roles only you can use app.config (both with web and worker role) however for web site configuration you can use web.config.

IF you just write what your final objective is in simple word, you sure will get exact assistance and suggestion on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help. Here is my objective...I have a working MVC app. Controller in this MVC app calls a web service endpoint (the service endpoint NOT in Azure - it is hosted elsewhere). When I run my MVC app in debug mode locally, app works fine. When I push the MVC app to Azure (tried both Azure website AND cloud service, by the way), the app does NOT work. Specifically, in controller I can comment out the service call within controller and all works fine again, so I am convinced service endpoint config info somehow not publishing.