# app.config in Web Role not copied in Azure SDK 1.8 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-sdk-.net

As suggested by [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228015/753737) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073251/753737) on Stack Overflow, I've added an `app.config` file to my web role in order to have some binding redirects available during the call of `Role.OnStart` in process `WaIISHost.exe`.

The trick works under the compute emulator, but when I deploy the hosted service on Azure I've got exceptions on role start -- namely the same `System.IO.FileLoadException` I would get on compute emulator if I omit the `app.config` file.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Azure SDK 1.8. The solution is built with .NET 4.0 and I've got several cloud projects for different purposes (debugging, production, ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've analyzed the `.cspkg` file created by Visual Studio and I've discovered that in the `bin` folder of the web role there was no `.config` file (as the linked answers suggested).

I then renamed the `app.config` file in the project to match the assembly name and I've set its `Copy local` property to `true` -- this way I've been able to successfully deploy my hosted service.

I don't know if this behavior is triggered by the presence of multiple cloud projects in the solution.

Comment: For some reason the project is not renaming app.config to <AssemblyName>.config, probably because it is a WebProject with a web.config.